# Does firewall access on the gossip port need to be opened for all nodes in a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

When configuring firewall access lists (ACLs), is it necessary to open the gossip port  between nodes for all nodes in a Cassandra cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each node in a Cassandra cluster "gossips" with every other node in the cluster on TCP internode port `7000` by default (`7001` if encryption is enabled) as part of normal operation.

Gossip is a peer-to-peer communication protocol Cassandra nodes use to communicate with each other in order to exchange information about the state of nodes in the cluster.

Being peer-to-peer, it is necessary for the firewall access to be bi-directional meaning the rules need to allow both inbound TCP and outbound TCP traffic on port `7000`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Erick's awesome answer; but this can also depend on your network/cloud setup.

In the case of an Apache Cassandra cluster which is fully-encapsulated in the same physical network or cloud region, the port for inter-node communication (7000 or 7001) only needs to be reachable by the other Cassandra nodes.  This means that it does *not* need to be accessible from the outside.

However, if you are building a cluster across multiple clouds or physical data centers, that port will need to be reachable from outside its immediate network, as shown below:
[image]

This is important to remember because each Cassandra node needs to be able to gossip with all other nodes in the cluster.